# Using the function A of R that calls the function B how to define the parametersof B

Tags: r, function

I am using the `rrcov::PcaHubert` function in R. I know that it calls the function `robustbase::CovMcd` to calculate the minimum covariance determinant. By default the CovMcd have the parameter raw.only=FALSE.

Is it possible to obligate the parameter raw.only of CovMcd be TRUE using the function PcaHubert?

Comment: check code of `PcaHubert`: if it has `...` as its parameter and so does `CovMcd` in its body, then you can pass `raw.only=TRUE` to `PcaHubert` and it will be passed to `CovMcd`.

Comment: It worked, thanks!